# Convert 2D List to pyspark DF

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Converting a List to the DF in spark, so need help in figuring out to map the 2d List to DG

```
a = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]]
```

to

```
--------Message--------|                            
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]      
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]     
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]  
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

tried direct mapping-

creating a schema and creating a df with the Data
throws
The length of the object  does not match with the length of fields

code

```
rdd = rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(a)

schema1 = StructType([
    StructField('Message', StringType(), True),

])
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(rdd,schema1)
df1.show()
```

Comment: You are providing `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]` as a value, which is of type `List[int]`. For a column of type `StringType`. Convert inner list to a string so `a` is a list of strings instead of a list of list of ints. OR change the column type so it can accommodate `List[int]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
>>> data = ([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]], [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]], [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]], [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]])
>>> schema = StructType([StructField('Message', ArrayType(IntegerType(), False))])
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
>>> df.show(truncate=False)
+---------------------------------+
|Message                          |
+---------------------------------+
|[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]|
|[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]|
|[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]|
|[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]|
+---------------------------------+
```